# about PC LR rigister value in stackinfo of linux kernel panic

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, stack

```
[ 1408.695236] pc : dwc3_stop_active_transfer.constprop.13+0x78/0xc0
[ 1408.695282] lr : dwc3_stop_active_transfer.constprop.13+0x74/0xc0
[ 1408.695318] sp : ffffff800b47baf0
```

In the stack information of a linux kernel panic, it is found that the value of the LR register is very close to the value of the PC register, and the addresses represented by their values ​​are all in a function. This doesn't look normal, unless there is a recursive call, but there is no recursion in this function. What is the reason for this situation?

Why are the PC LR register values ​​so close